# Getting empty body of page in feature spec using rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I am writing a feature spec for signin process.

```
describe 'the signin process', type: :feature do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it 'Should login with valid email password' do
    visit('/')
    fill_in 'user[email]', with: user.email
    fill_in 'user[password]', with: user.password
    click_button 'Log In'
    puts page.body
    expect(page).to have_content "Hello, you're managing"
  end
end
```

puts page.body is printing:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

when using rails 5.
But It is working in rail 3. It is printing the full page content of my home page when using rails 3.

Can someone help me please what is wrong with it?

application.html.haml

```
!!! transitional
%html(xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en")
  %head
    %meta{"http-equiv" => "X-UA-Compatible", :content => "chrome=1"}
    %meta{"http-equiv" => "Content-Type", :content => "text/html; charset=utf-8"}
    %link{:rel => "shortcut icon", :href => "/favicon.ico"}
    %title
      UgMO -
    = yield(:title) || "Save Water, Save Money, Save Earth"
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag 'application' 
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = yield(:head)
  %body{:class => "#{controller_name} #{action_name}"}
    = yield
```

Comment: How does your application.html.erb looks like?

Comment: This could be caused by any number of things, what does your `log/test.log` show ?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am having the same problem